# Finding index of a sublist

Tags: java, algorithm

The algorithm question. Let's say we have a list `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and a sublist `2, 3`, the algorithm should return the 1, because the sublist starts at index 1. If the specified sublist doesn't exist, the algorithm should return -1.

We have a defined `Node` data structure, which looks like this.

**Node.java**

```
private static class Node {

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    int value;
    Node next;
}
```

I've come up with the following algorithm, but I'm curious if it gets better than that in terms of performance.

```
public static int findSublistIndex(MyLinkedList list, MyLinkedList sublist) {
    if (list.head == null || sublist.head == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    int index = -1;

    for (Node l = list.head; l != null; l = l.next) {
        index ++;

        // encountered a value that is equal to the first value of a sublist
        if (l.value == sublist.head.value) {
            Node n = l;

            // check the rest of the sublist
            for (Node s = sublist.head; s != null; s = s.next) {
                if (n.value == s.value && s.next == null) {
                    return index;
                } else if (n.value == s.value) {
                    n = n.next;
                } else {
                    // the pointer should be set to l here to skip repeating? l = n;? -- doesn't work!
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Also, I'd like to practice some more list algorithm problems like this. Any website with such problems to recommend?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a review of a working algorithm and recommendations for places to practice programming.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So what's the problem? I'm asking for the possible improvements of the algorithm. And why not asking for advice where to practice...

Comment: This question is offtopic for stack overflow. See [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for posting questions like that. In addition, questions asking for recommendations of off-site resources are explicitly offtopic for the site.

Comment: There is another stack exchange site made just for this sort of question. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that your algorithm can throw NullPointerExceptions

Answer (score 3):

A better algorithm is [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). It is used to do a substring search, also could be used in your case. Its time cost is O(n+k), so it is a linear algorithm, and your algorithm is O(nk), which the n is the length of list and the k is the length of the sublist.

more algorithm challenge or code challenge, you could find in [codeForces](http://codeforces.com/) or [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/)